# Anyone figured out how to use WordPress MultiSite with Domain Mapping & SSL?

Tags: multisite, customization, domain-mapping, ssl

I've been looking all over to find a solution for SSL with WordPress MultiSite and Domain Mapping.  Ideally, I'd like to purchase an SSL cert for each domain (or potentially a wildcard cert) anyone have a solution that has worked for them.

I'm fearing that I overlooked this detail and will now have to split up my happy MU home in order to secure this domain properly.

Comment: Could a wildcard cert be purchased from someone like this? https://www.startssl.com/?app=40

Answer (score 4):

I am using multisite with domain mapping. I chose the `CNAME` option for pointing the mapped domain name.

My site is installed as a sub directory.

- http:// homesite.org/seedlivelihood

Files are served like so:

- https:// homesite.org/seedlivelihood/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/fancybox.min.css?ver=3.2.1

With domain mapping the site is at:

- seedlivelihood.org

Which is where my SSL is set up to be from.

Safari is choosing to not load `.js` and `.css` files that are coming from `homesite`.

> Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid.
>   You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “seedlivelihood.org” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk.

For any who wonder, this is how I solved this. I added this to `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} original.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname/wp-content/plugins
RewriteRule ^subdirectoryname(.*)$ https://newname.org$1 [L]
```

Once again, the situation was that the domain mapping was remapping what the viewer saw but not remapping any plugin files. Using this I was able to rewrite `original.org/subdirectoryname/wp-content/plugins/` to the new mapped domain: `newname.org/wp-content/plugins`

This solved my SSL woes and gave me the coveted greenlock. I do still have one file that gets created last minute with `.js` that somehow eludes the hack.

Answer (score 3):

On WordPress.com we have domain mapping and we have SSL but the two don't mix because we don't manage certs for mapped domains (AFAIK). We use SSL for wp-admin but not for blogs. Example:

```
http://andyskelton.com/
https://andyskelton.wordpress.com/wp-admin/
```

The SSL cert is for *.wordpress.com. If you try to visit the mapped domain over SSL you should get a warning from your browser.

This is fine if you only need SSL for wp-admin. Otherwise you must get a cert per domain and set those up in your web server.